# ResolvePackageNotFound error when creating conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I was trying to create a conda environment using `conda env create -n clam -f docs/clam.yaml`

I got the following result:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - mkl-service==2.3.0=py37he904b0f_0
  - libedit==3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
  - cffi==1.14.0=py37h2e261b9_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64==2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - zlib==1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - python-spams==2.6.1=py37h55324e4_1204
  - tensorflow-base==1.14.0=mkl_py37h7ce6ba3_0
  - matplotlib==3.1.1=py37h5429711_0
  - gmp==6.1.2=h6c8ec71_1
  - xorg-libice==1.0.10=h516909a_0
  - pyzmq==18.1.1=py37he6710b0_0
  - grpcio==1.27.2=py37hf8bcb03_0
  - xorg-kbproto==1.0.7=h14c3975_1002
  - libprotobuf==3.11.4=hd408876_0
  - ninja==1.9.0=py37hfd86e86_0
  - xorg-libxext==1.3.4=h516909a_0
  - expat==2.2.6=he6710b0_0
  - gobject-introspection==1.56.1=py37hbc4ca2d_2
  - freetype==2.9.1=h8a8886c_1
  - libtiff==4.1.0=h2733197_0
  - fontconfig==2.13.1=he4413a7_1000
  - xz==5.2.4=h14c3975_4
  - pixman==0.38.0=h7b6447c_0
  - numpy==1.18.1=py37h4f9e942_0
  - numpy-base==1.18.1=py37hde5b4d6_1
  - pytorch==1.3.1=py3.7_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0
  - ncurses==6.2=he6710b0_0
  - c-ares==1.15.0=h7b6447c_1001
  - gstreamer==1.14.0=hb453b48_1
  - harfbuzz==2.4.0=h37c48d4_1
  - zstd==1.3.7=h0b5b093_0
  - tk==8.6.8=hbc83047_0
  - xorg-libsm==1.2.3=h84519dc_1000
  - libcroco==0.6.13=h8d621e5_0
  - libstdcxx-ng==9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - pango==1.42.4=h7062337_3
  - h5py==2.10.0=nompi_py37h513d04c_102
  - xorg-libx11==1.6.9=h516909a_0
  - mkl_random==1.1.0=py37hd6b4f25_0
  - mkl_fft==1.0.15=py37ha843d7b_0
  - dbus==1.13.12=h746ee38_0
  - python==3.7.7=hcf32534_0_cpython
  - tensorflow==1.14.0=mkl_py37h45c423b_0
  - intel-openmp==2019.4=243
...
```

There's a total of 80+ lines.

How should I deal with this. I've seen people using pip, but in this case there's just too many packages and I'm not sure if it will work at all. Is there a better way?

The yaml file looks like this

```
name: deep_learning
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _tflow_select=2.3.0=mkl
  - absl-py=0.9.0=py37_0
  - astor=0.8.0=py37_0
  - attrs=19.3.0=py_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py37_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - c-ares=1.15.0=h7b6447c_1001
  - ca-certificates=2020.1.1=0
  - cairo=1.16.0=h18b612c_1001
  - certifi=2019.11.28=py37_1
  - cffi=1.14.0=py37h2e261b9_0
  - cudatoolkit=10.1.243=h6bb024c_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py37_0
  - cython=0.29.15=py37he6710b0_0
  - dbus=1.13.12=h746ee38_0
  - decorator=4.4.2=py_0
  - defusedxml=0.6.0=py_0
  - entrypoints=0.3=py37_0
  - expat=2.2.6=he6710b0_0
  - fontconfig=2.13.1=he4413a7_1000
  - freetype=2.9.1=h8a8886c_1
  - fribidi=1.0.9=h516909a_0
  - gast=0.3.3=py_0
  - gdk-pixbuf=2.36.9=1
  - glib=2.63.1=h5a9c865_0
  - gmp=6.1.2=h6c8ec71_1
  - gobject-introspection=1.56.1=py37hbc4ca2d_2
  - google-pasta=0.2.0=py_0
  - graphite2=1.3.13=h23475e2_0
  - grpcio=1.27.2=py37hf8bcb03_0
  - gst-plugins-base=1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1
  - gstreamer=1.14.0=hb453b48_1
  - h5py=2.10.0=nompi_py37h513d04c_102
  - harfbuzz=2.4.0=h37c48d4_1
  - hdf5=1.10.5=nompi_h3c11f04_1104
  - icu=58.2=h9c2bf20_1
  - importlib_metadata=1.5.0=py37_0
  - intel-openmp=2019.4=243
  - ipykernel=5.1.4=py37h39e3cac_0
  - ipython=7.13.0=py37h5ca1d4c_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py37_0
  - jedi=0.16.0=py37_1
  - jinja2=2.11.1=py_0
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - jupyter_client=6.1.0=py_0
  - jupyter_core=4.6.1=py37_0
  - keras-applications=1.0.8=py_0
  - keras-preprocessing=1.1.0=py_1
  - kiwisolver=1.1.0=py37he6710b0_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - libblas=3.8.0=14_mkl
  - libcroco=0.6.13=h8d621e5_0
  - libedit=3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - libgcc=7.2.0=h69d50b8_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libgfortran-ng=7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libiconv=1.15=h516909a_1006
  - liblapack=3.8.0=14_mkl
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libprotobuf=3.11.4=hd408876_0
  - librsvg=2.46.2=h33a7fed_1
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h1bed415_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libtiff=4.1.0=h2733197_0
  - libuuid=2.32.1=h14c3975_1000
  - libxcb=1.13=h1bed415_1
  - libxml2=2.9.9=hea5a465_1
  - markdown=3.1.1=py37_0
  - markupsafe=1.1.1=py37h7b6447c_0
  - matplotlib=3.1.1=py37h5429711_0
  - mistune=0.8.4=py37h7b6447c_0
  - mkl=2019.4=243
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py37he904b0f_0
  - mkl_fft=1.0.15=py37ha843d7b_0
  - mkl_random=1.1.0=py37hd6b4f25_0
  - nbconvert=5.6.1=py37_0
  - nbformat=5.0.4=py_0
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_0
  - ninja=1.9.0=py37hfd86e86_0
  - notebook=6.0.1=py37_0
  - numpy=1.18.1=py37h4f9e942_0
  - numpy-base=1.18.1=py37hde5b4d6_1
  - olefile=0.46=py37_0
  - openssl=1.1.1e=h7b6447c_0
  - pandoc=2.2.3.2=0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py37_1
  - pango=1.42.4=h7062337_3
  - parso=0.6.2=py_0
  - pcre=8.43=he6710b0_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=py37_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py37_0
  - pillow=7.0.0=py37hb39fc2d_0
  - pip=20.0.2=py37_1
  - pixman=0.38.0=h7b6447c_0
  - prometheus_client=0.7.1=py_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.4=py_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.4=0
  - ptyprocess=0.6.0=py37_0
  - pycparser=2.20=py_0
  - pygments=2.6.1=py_0
  - pyparsing=2.4.6=py_0
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py37h05f1152_2
  - pyrsistent=0.15.7=py37h7b6447c_0
  - python=3.7.7=hcf32534_0_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - python-spams=2.6.1=py37h55324e4_1204
  - pytorch=1.3.1=py3.7_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0
  - pytz=2019.3=py_0
  - pyzmq=18.1.1=py37he6710b0_0
  - qt=5.9.7=h5867ecd_1
  - readline=8.0=h7b6447c_0
  - scipy=1.4.1=py37h0b6359f_0
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py37_0
  - setuptools=45.3.0=py37_0
  - sip=4.19.8=py37hf484d3e_0
  - six=1.14.0=py37_0
  - sqlite=3.31.1=h7b6447c_0
  - tensorboard=1.14.0=py37hf484d3e_0
  - tensorflow=1.14.0=mkl_py37h45c423b_0
  - tensorflow-base=1.14.0=mkl_py37h7ce6ba3_0
  - tensorflow-estimator=1.14.0=py_0
  - termcolor=1.1.0=py37_1
  - terminado=0.8.3=py37_0
  - testpath=0.4.4=py_0
  - tk=8.6.8=hbc83047_0
  - tornado=6.0.4=py37h7b6447c_1
  - traitlets=4.3.3=py37_0
  - wcwidth=0.1.8=py_0
  - werkzeug=1.0.0=py_0
  - wheel=0.34.2=py37_0
  - wrapt=1.12.1=py37h7b6447c_1
  - xorg-kbproto=1.0.7=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-libice=1.0.10=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libsm=1.2.3=h84519dc_1000
  - xorg-libx11=1.6.9=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxext=1.3.4=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxrender=0.9.10=h516909a_1002
  - xorg-renderproto=0.11.1=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-xextproto=7.3.0=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-xproto=7.0.31=h14c3975_1007
  - xz=5.2.4=h14c3975_4
  - zeromq=4.3.1=he6710b0_3
  - zipp=2.2.0=py_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.3.7=h0b5b093_0
  - pip:
    - 2to3==1.0
    - asciitree==0.3.3
    - asgiref==2.3.2
    - asn1crypto==1.2.0
    - async-timeout==3.0.1
    - atomicwrites==1.3.0
    - autobahn==19.5.1
    - automat==0.8.0
    - bleach==3.1.0
    - channels==2.1.7
    - chardet==3.0.4
    - click==7.0
    - codacy-coverage==1.3.11
    - constantly==15.1.0
    - coverage==4.5.4
    - cryptography==2.3.1
    - daphne==2.2.5
    - django==2.2.7
    - djangorestframework==3.9.4
    - fasteners==0.15
    - filelock==3.0.12
    - flask==1.0.2
    - future==0.18.2
    - hyperlink==19.0.0
    - idna==2.8
    - imagecodecs==2020.2.18
    - imageio==2.6.1
    - incremental==17.5.0
    - intervaltree==3.0.2
    - itsdangerous==1.1.0
    - joblib==0.14.0
    - jsonfield2==3.0.3
    - jsonschema==2.6.0
    - lmdb==0.98
    - lxml==4.2.1
    - lz4==2.2.1
    - monotonic==1.5
    - mypy-extensions==0.4.3
    - ndg-httpsclient==0.5.0
    - networkx==2.4
    - numcodecs==0.6.4
    - opencv-python==4.1.1.26
    - openslide-python==1.1.1
    - openslides==3.0
    - packaging==19.2
    - pandas==0.25.3
    - pkgconfig==1.5.1
    - pluggy==0.13.1
    - progressbar2==3.43.1
    - protobuf==3.10.0
    - py==1.8.0
    - pyasn1==0.4.3
    - pyflann==1.6.14
    - pyhamcrest==1.9.0
    - pyopenssl==18.0.0
    - pypdf2==1.26.0
    - pytest==4.6.2
    - pytest-cov==2.7.1
    - python-utils==2.3.0
    - pywavelets==1.1.1
    - pyyaml==3.13
    - requests==2.22.0
    - requests-mock==1.5.2
    - roman==3.1
    - scikit-image==0.16.2
    - scikit-learn==0.22.1
    - seaborn==0.9.0
    - sklearn==0.0
    - sortedcontainers==2.1.0
    - sqlparse==0.3.0
    - tensorboardx==1.9
    - tifffile==2020.2.16
    - toml==0.10.0
    - torchsummary==1.5.1
    - torchvision==0.1.8
    - tox==3.13.2
    - tqdm==4.37.0
    - twisted==19.7.0
    - txaio==18.8.1
    - typing-extensions==3.7.4.1
    - urllib3==1.25.7
    - virtualenv==16.7.7
    - webencodings==0.5.1
    - websockets==8.1
    - zarr==2.3.2
    - zope-interface==4.6.0
prefix: /home/fedshyvana/anaconda3/envs/deep_learning
```

Comment: Please post `clam.yaml`

Comment: @MattThompson I've edited the question

Comment: The builds clearly indicate the original platform was Linux. What platform are you attempting to install on? As a first step, you could try stripping the build specifications from the YAML file. E.g., `cffi=1.14.0=py37h2e261b9_0` should be modified to `cffi=1.14.0`.

Comment: I'm running this on a mac but I'm new to this so I'm not sure what to adjust. I've tried stripping the build specifications but it seems to run infinitely, constantly telling me found conflicts and then it takes several minutes to examine the conflict. Later on it just loops back when it finished checking.